# checking for cookie and setting it after closing jquery dialog modal

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

this is my fist time posting but I've been searching and using this site as a great reference tool for a while. My jquery knowledge is little to none, I've been learning on the fly for a project that has been handed to me. Basically I want the code to check for the cookie, if the cookie is there don't display the jquery modal. If it's not there then the jquery modal would display and then set the cookie after the user closes it.

Here is what I have tried to piece together so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/storage/jquery-validation/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
 var seen = $.cookie('modal');
 if (seen == null) {
// a workaround for a flaw in the demo system
(http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );


$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:400,
      width:600,
      modal: true,
  buttons: {
                I agree": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      $.cookie('modal', 'true', { path: '/', expires: 365 });
            },
        },
    });
     }
});
</script>
```

I hope that makes a little sense. I appreciate any help anyone can offer.